# Language (English) learning software for PC (Ubuntu & Windows)

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, dictionary

I want to find analog of this app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funeasylearn.english ) for PC (for Ubuntu and Windows). (I want multi-language program for learning words.)

1. I don't want to install Android application on PC as in this topic https://superuser.com/questions/371280/how-to-install-android-os-and-android-apps-on-pc .
2. Basically I want program with English dictionary (for learning English) for Russian users. But I want to learn Spanish too.
3. I want open source or free program, but with dictionary included already. I don't want to create full own dictionary, but ability for adding new words is welcome. If program is without dictionary included, then it will be good if program will use GoldenDict dictionaries:

   - StarDict (.ifo/.dict./.idx/.syn)
   - ABBYY Lingvo .dsl dictionary files
   - Babylon (.bgl) dictionaries
   - XDXF dictionary
   - Dictd (.index / .dict / .dz) dictionary files
4. I want to learn random words (or in game format), and I don't want to typing words in dictionary search by myself (like in GoldenDict).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest [Anki](http://ankisrs.net).

- Native PC program (Windows/Linux/Mac)
- Many Russian-English decks ready to use ([example](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/831667366) [more](https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)). Lots of Spanish decks too.
- Ability to import word lists (CSV, Excel). Actually a lot of dictionaries are already available as shared decks that you can easily download from within the app
- Shows you random words, and re-ask the ones you have a hard time remembering. It is [Spaced Repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition). Nearly as fun and addictive as a game :-)
- Open source
- Sync with mobile if you want

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Might a web app be an option for you?  If so, check out [Duolingo](https://ru.duolingo.com).  Duolingo is a free platform for learning languages in a simple, game-y manner.  Languages are broken down into categories for easier learning, and there's an XP and leveling system to help with motivation.  There are courses to and from many languages.  For Russian speakers, they do have both [English](https://ru.duolingo.com/course/en/ru/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD) and [Spanish](https://ru.duolingo.com/course/es/ru/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD), as well as French and German.  (They do offer many more languages if you start from English.)

Hope this helps!